# AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization with abstract class implementing interface

Tags: moq, autofixture

I use AutoFixture 3.21.0, AutoFixture.AutoMoq 3.21.0, NUnit 2.6.3 and Moq 4.2.1409.1722.

I have the following interface, two *abstract* classes (one of them implements this interface), and two unit tests.

Tests pass.

```cs
    public interface IMigration
    {
        IMigrationParameters MigrationParameters { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class AbstractSutWithoutInterface
    {
        public IMigrationParameters MigrationParameters { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class AbstractSutWithInterface : IMigration
    {
        public IMigrationParameters MigrationParameters { get; set; }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestAbstractSutWithoutInterface()
        {
            var fixture = new Fixture();
            fixture.Customize( new AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization() );

            var mock = fixture.Create<AbstractSutWithoutInterface>();

            Assert.IsNotNull( mock.MigrationParameters ); // test passes
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestAbstractSutWithInterface()
        {
            var fixture = new Fixture();
            fixture.Customize( new AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization() );

            var mock = fixture.Create<AbstractSutWithInterface>();

            Assert.IsNull( mock.MigrationParameters ); // test passes
        }
    }
```

My question is why *AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization* has different behavior for abstract classes depending on whether property is defined by interface or not? In first test property is asserted to be not null but in second test is null. If classes are not abstract, property injection works as expected for both classes.

Comment: Are those classes missing the `abstract` keyword?

Comment: @PatrickQuirk Thank you for pointing out missing keyword in source code. I have corrected it.

Comment: I can't reproduce, in both cases they are not null for me.  I'm using the latest AutoFixture version, which are you using?

Comment: @PatrickQuirk I use AutoFixture 3.21.0, AutoFixture.AutoMoq 3.21.0, NUnit 2.6.3, Moq 4.2.1409.1722. Please try to use the latest Moq version.

Comment: @sgnsajgon Thank you for reporting this :) Integration issues such as this are insanely hard to spot.

Comment: This bug has been fixed in [AutoFixture.AutoMoq 3.24.2](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoMoq/3.24.2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 2015/04/15**

This bug has been fixed in [AutoFixture.AutoMoq 3.24.2](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoMoq/3.24.2). See details [here](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/324#issuecomment-93405013).

**Update 2014/11/03**

This is now being tracked on AutoFixture's GitHub, [Issue 324](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/324).

Also, the last working version of Moq is 4.2.1402.2112, you can downgrade to that one instead of 4.0.

---

I can only reproduce this with the latest version of Moq (4.2.1409.1722).

I'm looking into this right now, and it *seeeeems* like a bug has been introduced in the latest version of Moq, but it might be by design, I'm not sure yet.

In the meantime, please use version 4.0.10827. To downgrade, go to Tools -> NuGet Packet Manager -> Package Manager Console and type:

```
Uninstall-Package Moq -Force
Install-Package Moq -Version 4.0.10827
```

I'll update this answer with my findings.